# Is the “Empty String” a term in First Order Logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am sitting on the couch thinking about one of my trivial and (almost!) meaningless mathematical problems.
Let me explain: terms are recursively defined in First Order Logic starting from symbols for individual variables and symbols for individual constants.

As I was thinking about considering constants as nullary functions I ran into the problem of accepting the empty string to be a term.
Is this assumption correct?

Comment: There are no empty terms, or else nonsense like `4 + = ( ÷ f(,,,7,) )`  and `∀y.` would also be terms.

Comment: I’m completely aware of it but the empty set is the sole argument of a nullary function and should be considered a term in that case...

Comment: @DanieleLeo No, the empty set is not the argument of a nullary function any more than a set with two elements is the argument of a binary function. A binary function has two arguments; a nullary function has no arguments. E.g. in Polish notation we would write "$+(a,b)$" not "$+(\{a,b\})$." It may be helpful to point out explicitly that what *is* true is that $\emptyset$ is a *set of* terms - each element of $\emptyset$ is a term!

Comment: @DanieleLee:  We should be careful of conflating an empty string with the empty set, as your last Comment seems to do.  That said, there does seem to be a role for empty strings as *formulas* in rigorous development of first-order logic.  I don't see the same need for empty strings as *terms* (in part because any symbol for a nullary function already serves intrinsically as a term).

Comment: @hardmath What's the role of empty strings as formulas? The empty string certainly isn't a formula in any presentation I've ever seen, and I don't see how we'd treat it as one. Indeed the same argument as for terms applies: the recursive definition of "formula" begins with nonempty strings and only ever produces longer strings from shorter strings.

Comment: (In particular, note that an expression like "$\Gamma\vdash{}{}{}$" occurring in the context of sequent calculus is really shorthand for "$\Gamma\vdash\{\}$" - we're never viewing the empty string itself as a syntactic object.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'm thinking of its use in connection with [the logical turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)).

Comment: @hardmath See my previous comment - it's just shorthand, and it's certainly never being treated as a formula. (Similarly, "$\vdash A$" just means "$\emptyset\vdash A$.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the recursive definition of "term." The base clauses are:

- Variables are terms, and
- Constant symbols (if present in the language) are terms.

The recursion clause meanwhile only lets you build longer terms: it says that whenever $f$ is an $n$-ary function symbol in the language and $t_1,...,t_n$ are terms, then $f(t_1,...,t_n)$ is a term.

*(Incidentally, if we view constant symbols as nullary function symbols, then the second base clause is subsumed by the recursion clause.)*

At no point does the empty string enter: we start with nonempty strings and only go "less empty" from there.

Comment: Thanks for answering Noah! :) The recursive definition is clear to me. Now let $c_0, c_1$ be two symbols for constants. What's the way of writing the term $c_0 + c_1$ using nullary function symbols? I was thinking about $f_0(()) + f_1(())$ but the empty string must be a term this way. It's way difficult to be clear, hope I was sufficient enough...

Comment: @DanieleLeo Well, you've already done it. But if you want to "get Polish" here, which I think is probably a good idea, you'd write "$+(c_1(),c_2())$." The terms occurring here are the whole thing $+(c_1(),c_2())$ and the sub-expressions $c_1()$ and $c_2()$. Every argument of (say) $c_1()$ is a term, but there aren't any of those, so we've found all the terms occurring here.

Comment: Maybe it helps to think about it this way. Any term $t$ has a **set of immediate subterms** (= the set of its arguments) $Set(t)$. A nullary function symbol $c$ (or if you prefer, $c()$) gets $Set(c)=\emptyset$. But that doesn't mean that $\emptyset$ is a term, just that it's a *set of* terms.

Comment: Or, note that all this is analogous to the fact that $\emptyset\not\in\emptyset$.

Comment: Ooook, a good point here, thanks. An assignement now maps the argument (we have none as you pointed out) of $c_0$ and $c_1$ in the empty set if I inferred correct, did I? The now interpreted nullary function will assign an element of the domain of the interpretation to get us the desired constant

Comment: @DanieleLeo Yes (if I understand your comment correctly).